# Recover drive from corrupted `dd`

Tags: hard-drive, dd, sata

Two years ago I took my hard drive and zero-d out the drive using `dd`. However, I was a little impatient so I cancelled out the process and restarted the computer. The result is that I got an `Input-Output error`. Are there any solution to check and fix these errors?

**edit 1:** I did `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb` to zero out the drive. I cancelled when it performed the action for 5 minutes.

Comment: Input-output errors occurs due to damaged parts in hard-drives,They aren't any way concerned to `dd` command, it is just used to copy, it is very similar to `cp` command but `dd` never bothers about security or permissions of certain file, it just does everything under low-level bits,i.e., it copys in terms of bits.

Comment: @looserof7 I don't think it's a hardware error. Like, I cancelled the `dd` progress and all I did next was restart the computer. After that I can't boot into the drive anymore. Also I have another drive that suffered the same thing when I corrupted `dd` but it's a USB one.

Comment: But you see it still in the device list? Try doing a complete and clean new `dd`on it if.

Comment: what have you done with `dd` command, did you copy something to hard-drive or hard-drive partition. Can you modify your question by specifying what command you have used.

Comment: @looserof7 I zero-d out the drive

Comment: @Videonauth On GParted, yes. Tried to `dd` again but it gives error.  The I/O error.

Comment: Input/Output error isn't considered to dd command, it means your hard-drive has superblocks, so it is better to get a new hard-drive

Comment: @looserof7 Wait what is a superblock? Also I had this drive worked before doing `dd`

Comment: When did you use dd, it's two years back

Comment: @looserof7 where

Comment: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=165237 check this link, even that guy had similar problem.

Comment: @looserof7 I don't want the data back just want the HDD to work.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see the drive still in Gparted, you can go on and create a new partition table for it by starting gParted and then choose the proper device, go to the menu bar and click on `Devices --> create partition table` as format you can choose `msdos` afterwards build your partitions like you want and apply it.

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: The drive IS in GParted but the error says No.